# I want to list the students who are not registered in the class

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

A student can register for more than one class. I want to list the students who are not registered in the class. But I couldn't find where I went wrong.

Here is my code listing what's in the class:

```
SELECT users.id as id, users.rank, users.name_surname, users.status 
FROM userClasses,users 
WHERE userClasses.user = users.id 
AND userClasses.classes = 2
```

Here is my code that lists those not registered with the class:

```
SELECT users.id as id, users.rank, users.name_surname, users.status
FROM userClasses,users
WHERE userClasses.user = users.id
AND userClasses.classes <> 2
```

Can you help with this?

I also tried this code, it does not give correct results.

```
SELECT users.* FROM
( SELECT users.*, userClasses.classes
  FROM users
      LEFT JOIN userClasses
          ON users.id = userClasses.user
  WHERE ((userClasses.classes <> 2)
             OR (userClasses.classes IS NULL)) AND users.`rank`=1 )
    users
    LEFT JOIN classes
        ON users.classes = classes.id;
```

Comment: Can you explain bit more about the tables you are using, it is not clear what are the tables and the data in the tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT users.id as id, users.rank, users.name_surname, users.status
FROM userClasses
INNER JOIN users ON userClasses.user = id
WHERE userClasses.classes <> '2'
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.